# Good resources for handling IE7-8 specific Javascript CSS bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

After a week of coding finally have my site working across all browsers and mobile devices. I made the mistake of not viewing in IE8 and IE 7 until now.

Can anyone share some steps in resolving IE7-8 compatibility issues when using jQuery and CSS?

What are some first steps to try?

If a site isn't too complex does it make sense to do server side detection and serve up an IE only site?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you ask about specific issues.

Comment: @user1090190 I stopped reading after the phrase "hard coding"...XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what problems you are running into. There are a lot of resources, such as [PositionIsEverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) or [HasLayout](http://haslayout.net/css/), on the web complaining about & explaining different IE bugs (peekaboo, double margin etc).

It is useful to use a tool such as [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to see your page on actual IE versions.

Answer (score 2):

There should be few if any issues in jQuery - thats one of the big benefits to using jQuery or a similar library in the first place. Chances are if there is a js issue then its something you wrote as opposed to something internal to jQuery.

In both cases the bets thing to do is simply know the majority of the big things that differ in support. the Quirksmode.org compatibility tables are good for this. If you know the differences in the first place you are going to be able to create solutions up front before you ever get to testing and avoid the issues. Beyond that test cross-browser early on in the process - not at the last minute.